# Put a rectangle with a circle in one line CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]
I make a rectangle and a circle in html and css. but i want to put them together. what can i do?

```css
.rect-circ {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.rectangle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgb(85, 80, 80);
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.circle {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgb(85, 80, 80);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect-circ">
  <div class="rectangle"> </div>
  <div class="circle"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One line CSS. What do you mean by that ?

Comment: If you want one line CSS, try minification (:

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean, but if you want a rectangle and circle in the same vertical alignment, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-rectangle-circle-tem7x?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean you want the elements on the same place overlapping eachother.

I've added `position: relative;` to the wrapper (`.rect-circ`) so I can position elements reletive to this wrapper.

I've added `position: abosulute; left: 0;` to both the circle and the rectangle to position them on the left side of the wrapper.

```css
.rect-circ {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgb(85, 80, 80);
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect-circ">
  <div class="rectangle"> </div>
  <div class="circle"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this css

```
.rect-circ{ 
    width: 30px;
    height: auto; 
    margin-left: 100px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;   
 }
```